# Need to transfer RAW E-Mail messages to server. What is the best method?

Tags: email, networking, encryption, zip

I need to transfer raw E-Mail messages to a server for processing.  The raw e-mail message is actually a txt file.  Each txt file contains 1 raw E-Mail message.

I need to process each e-mail one at a time and get a response from the server for each E-Mail so I need to submit each message one at at time and not in bulk.

What is the best method for doing this?  I thought about zipping and encrypting each message then sending it to the server but then the server would have to unzip and decrypt each one and then process it.

Can someone recommend another way to do this where I could send it to the server with the least amount of overhead and processing on both the client and server?

Edit:  The server is home made server software running on Windows Server.  I can make the server interpret anything that comes into it.  It does not need to be a certain protocol or anything in that regard.  I was just wondering about the best method to package up or transmit the e-mail txt file to the server with the least overhead.

Comment: Do you have a shell account on the server? If so, just `scp` them over. Where to put them depends on the server and its config. Tell us the type of server (SMTP, IMAP, POP ...?) the OS and the software you need to interact with

Comment: Revised my original question with the details that you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with sending the e-mail txt as e-mail and have a script to parse it (and return the result). Actually that's what an email server is made for - receiving and handling many email messages.